# Content written before fork() present in output twice

Tags: c, printf, stdio, fork

I wrote the following C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("A");
    if(fork() == 0){
        printf("B");
    }
    else{
        printf("C");
    }
}
```

The output I got is:

```
ACAB
```

I expected this code to print A only once.
Can anyone explain this output?

Comment: It's ideal to use a subject line that describes _why_ or _how_ something is "not behaving as expected". I've tried to improve this one appropriately.

Comment: this is tricky. some employer likes to ask this. `fork` copy every data from parent to user, including the IO buffer. this is the side effect of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is not flushing the buffers before `fork`-ing, thus both processes will write it.

Add this before `fork()`:

```
fflush(0); // Flush all output-streams
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'A' is stored in a buffer and flushed by both processes when they exit.

Comment: Okay so after a fork() call, the child also creates a copy of parent's  buffer which is why I was getting this output.